# Examples with prefix 専 (せん)

Tags: grammar, prefixes

Jisho says that 専 (せん) can be used as a prefix with meaning "having a fetish for ...; specializing in ...; majoring in ...​".

https://jisho.org/search/%E5%B0%82

However, I can't find any example with this prefix.

Then, I've tried to create my own example.

専白兵戦のファイター (fighter specializing in close combat)

but I don't know if this would be okay or wrong.

**Could you please correct this if needed and give me other examples of the usage of the prefix 専 (せん)?**

I would like to understand how is this prefix used.

Comment: Jisho indicates it's a slang term. Then it should be a suffix, not a prefix. It must be talking about things like デブ専.

Comment: Oh, I see! Are there other typical examples apart from デブ専 or is suffix 専 only used for this word?

Comment: I would suggest starting a new question to ask about the suffix usage. Or you can rewrite the main question above, if you prefer.

Comment: デブ is an offensive word (from today's standard) that you must truly avoid, and デブ専 is quite vulgar. I recommend forgetting such usages altogether. ;-)